# How do i see if all my checkboxes are checked or not?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to check if all the checkboxes on my page is not checked. This is what I came up with:

```
var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("cl");
console.log(allCheckboxes);

function checkCheckbox(allCheckboxes) {
  for (let index = 0; index < allCheckboxes.length; index++) {
    if (allCheckboxes[index].checked == false) {
      console.log(allCheckboxes[index] + "is UNCHECKED")
    } 
    else {
      console.log(allCheckboxes[index] + "is CHECKED")
    }  
  }
}
```

I have set the class 'cl' to every checkbox in my HTML-file.

When I run the function, it will anyways ay that everything is unchecked, even if there is one that is checked.

Where i execute the function:

```
function generateGraph(url) {
  //Here are the arrayes used to find the data in the json file
  //These will be reset everytime the generate button is pressed
  var arrayTheta = [];
  var arrayRange = [];
  var mcsArray = [];
  var channelArray = [];
  var caseArray = [];

  
  //Getting the data from json-file (function) {NOTE: gotta figure out a way to get data from multible JSON-files}
  async function getData(arrayRange, arrayTheta, url, graphLabels, mcsArray, channelArray, caseArray,) {  

    //Gets data from the JSON-file, were the url is the box that is checked
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const productData = await response.json();


    for (let index = 0; index < productData.length; index++) {
      arrayTheta.push(productData[index].theta);
      arrayRange.push(productData[index].Range);
    }


    //The graph, copied from Chart.js, but changed for our prefrence
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    window.myChart = new Chart(ctx,{ // having the "myChart" as a window. insted of const was sugested by someone on StackOverflow (makes the const global, i can therefor use it in another function)
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: arrayTheta,
            datasets: [{
                label: graphLabels,
                data: arrayRange,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',

                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                pointRadius: 0,
                //The line under "tension: 0.4" makes the graph a little bit smoother
                tension: 0.4
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
                ,x: {
                  display: true,
                  type: 'linear'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = false // Will enable the clear button

    checkCheckbox(allCheckboxes)
  }
```

I execute the function inside of another function.

HTML:

```
        <div class="grey-container">
            <!--FIRST SPAN::Device-->
            <!--IMPORTANT NOTE -- Span is for individual checklist-->
            <span>
                <ul>
                    <h3>Link Database (AP-STA)</h3>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cl" class="device" id="PRM2143-PRM2142" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="PRM2143-PRM2142">PRM2143-PRM2142</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRM2143-PRM2143" class="device" id="PRM2143-PRM2143" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="PRM2143-PRM2143">PRM2143-PRM2143</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRM2143-PRM2141" class="device" id="PRM2143-PRM2141" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="PRM2143-PRM2141">PRM2143-PRM2141</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRM2141dish-PRM2142" class="device" id="PRM2141dish-PRM2142" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="PRM2141dish-PRM2142">PRM2141dish-PRM2142</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRM2141dish-PRM2141dish" class="device" id="PRM2141dish-PRM2141dish" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="PRM2141dish-PRM2141dish">PRM2141dish-PRM2141dish</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PRM2141dish-PRM2141" class="device" id="PRM2141dish-PRM2141" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="PRM2141dish-PRM2141">PRM2141dish-PRM2141</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>

            <!--SECOND SPAN::Case-->
            <span>
                <ul>
                    <h3>Case Selection (AP-STA)</h3>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Boresight-Boresight" id="Boresight-Boresight" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="Boresight-Boresight">Boresight-Boresight</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Omni-Boresight" id="Omni-Boresight" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="Omni-Boresight">Omni-Boresight</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Omni-Maxscan" id="Omni-Maxscan" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="Omni-Maxscan">Omni-Maxscan</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Maxscan-Maxscan" id="Maxscan-Maxscan" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="Maxscan-Maxscan">Maxscan-Maxscan</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>

            <!--THIRD SPAN::mcs-->   
            <span>
                <ul>
                    <h3>MCS</h3>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="0" id="mcs0" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs0">0</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="mcs1" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs1">1</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="mcs2" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs2">2</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="mcs3" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs3">3</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="mcs4" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs4">4</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="5" id="mcs5" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs5">5</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="6" id="mcs6" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs6">6</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="7" id="mcs7" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs7">7</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="8" id="mcs8" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs8">8</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="9" id="mcs9" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs9">9</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="10" id="mcs10" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs10">10</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="11" id="mcs11" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs11">11</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="12" id="mcs12" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="mcs12">12</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>

            <!--THIRD SPAN::Channel-->   
            <span>
                <ul>
                    <h3>Channel</h3>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="channel1" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="channel1">1</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="channel2" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="channel2">2</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="channel3" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="channel3">3</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="channel4" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="channel4">4</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="5" id="channel5" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="channel5">5</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="6" id="channel6" class="cl" onchange="document.getElementById('reset').disabled = false, document.getElementById('generate').disabled = false">
                        <label for="channel6">6</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </span>

            <div id="button-container">
                <button type="button" id="generate" onclick="generateGraph(url)" disabled><span>Generate</span> Chart</button>
                <button type="button" id="clear" onclick="clearCanvas()" disabled><span>Clear</span> Chart</button>
                <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="resetCheckbox()" disabled><span>Reset</span> Checkboxes</button>
            </div>

            
            <!--Canvas for charts-->
            <div id="canvas-container">
                <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
                <canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
            </div>
```

I hope this is enough code to help me, but if it is needed more information, just ask.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal repuducable example? For this see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: use `===` and check if result changes

Comment: Your code is missing where you execute `checkCheckbox` and your HTML. That would potentially help supporters find problems in your code.

Comment: `[...allCheckboxes].every(checkbox => checkbox.checked)`?

Comment: @NickVu I have now edited the post with more information. Is it enough to help me?

Comment: @evolutionxbox is this what you mean:
```
function checkCheckbox(allCheckboxes) {
  for (let index = 0; index < allCheckboxes.length; index++) {
    if (allCheckboxes.every(checkbox => checkbox.checked)) {
      console.log(allCheckboxes[index] + "is UNCHECKED")
    } 
    else {
      console.log(allCheckboxes[index] + "is CHECKED")
    }  
  }
}
```

If so, it came with this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: allCheckboxes.every is not a function

Comment: See Andy's answer. You must convert the element list into an array before using array methods

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply check whether *all* checkboxes are checked or not, you could go about it like this:

```js
const areAllChecked = () => {
  const allChecked = !Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')).some(box => box.checked !== true);
  console.log("All checked? ", allChecked);
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> Check 1</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox"> Check 2</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox"> Check 3</label>

<p><button onclick="areAllChecked()">Are all checked?</button></p>
```

The key is that you do not need to look at all checkboxes. It suffices to find one that is not checked to conclude that not all are checked. To practice some logic:

`allAreChecked = !someAreNotChecked`

This is what [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) does. It stops looking at the rest of the array once it finds one item that fulfils the condition.

If you would like to do more comparisons, it would be better to simply take the count of checked boxes and compare it to the number of all checkboxes.

```js
const allCheckboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'));
const checkedBoxes = allCheckboxes.filter(box => box.checked === true);
const uncheckedCount = allCheckboxes.length - checkedBoxes.length;
```

Comment: This works like a charm!!
But what do i need to do if i want to switch it around? (check if everything is UNchecked)

Comment: `allAreUnchecked = !someAreChecked`. So in code it would be `const allUnchecked = Array.from(…).some(box => box.checked === true);`

Comment: I added some lines about a more general approach that counts boxes, which would allow you to set disabled attributes on dependent buttons or set a “check all” checkbox to its indeterminate state.

Comment: If this helped you with your issue it would be great if you could accept this answer.